# Create multiple TextFields with a delete button using JavaFX with FXML

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I am looking for a way to  allow a user to add a multiple TextFields by hitting a create button then for each created TextField I want to associated it with a delete button to allow the user to delete any of the Textfields.

Here is what I came across thus far.

```
@FXML
    private VBox pane_main_grid;
@FXML
private void AddTextField(ActionEvent event)  {     
 TextField newField = new TextField();
 pane_main_grid.getChildren().add(newField);}
```

How can I keep track of what is created vs what I want to delete? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a button right next to it to remove it:

```
@FXML
private void AddTextField(ActionEvent event) {
    final HBox parent = new HBox(5.0); // 5.0 is the distance between the field and the button; hbox is the parent of both

    TextField field = new TextField();
    Button button = new Button("Close"); // the button to "close" the textfield
    button.setOnAction((e) -> pane_main_grid.getChildren().remove(parent)); // button click removes the hbox
    button.setPrefSize(100, 27); // only if you're using a custom font / styling
    HBox.setHgrow(field, Priority.ALWAYS); // field should always grow
    HBox.setHgrow(button, Priority.NEVER); // button should never grow

    parent.getChildren().setAll(field, button); // add the textfield and the button to the hbox
    pane_main_grid.getChildren().add(parent); // add the hbox to your main grid
}
```

Comment: This works with minor tweaks,  I had to modify the button action to button.setOnAction((e) as I couldn't use (event) twice. and I had to set the button size button.setPrefSize(100, 27); to display the "Close" text properly. Please update your answer so i can accept it. Thanks so much for you help!!!

Comment: @Moe No problem. I edited my answer. The `button.setPrefSize(100, 27)` should only be needed if you're using a custom fon't. When I tested it, it was the right size without setting it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
private void AddTextField(ActionEvent event) {
    final TextField newField = new TextField();
    pane_main_grid.getChildren().add(newField);

    final Button deleteBtn = new Button("delete");
    pane_main_grid.getChildren().add(deleteBtn);
    deleteBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pane_main_grid.getChildren().remove(newField);
                    pane_main_grid.getChildren().remove(deleteBtn);
                }
            });           
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `Platform.runLater`? EventHandlers will always be invoked on the JavaFX Application Thread.

Comment: You are running in a thread and are affecting the cause of this thread. I feel that it is safer to use 'runLater' in such a case. I could be wrong and you might not need it here.

Comment: that's true, but any Listeners or Handlers on JavaFX Objects should never be invoked on a Thread other than the JavaFX Application Thread. EventHandlers will never be invoked on another Thread since they're called from JavaFX itself. When you're changing a Property, all Listeners will be invoked on the same Thread where you change the Value of the Property. BUT you should also never change a Property on a Thread other than the JavaFX Application Thread because UI Update Bindings won't use `Platform.runLater` internal and they must be done on the JavaFX Application Thread